Poisson two-way ANOVA test for Before and After treatment (including a control)
I am having trouble to determine what type of test to use in this experimental design:
My data are like this:

I got 10 treatment sites and 4 control sites
Control sites are outside an area in which a treatment (i.e., construction will occur), and treatment sites is where the treatment will occur
I got 128 repetitions for each treatment and control site, 64 BEFORE and 64 AFTER treatment was applied. This means that the data is paired.
I got four seasons of the year (spring, autumn, summer, winter) -- maybe this can be treated as a random variable

I want to know if the period AFTER treatment will result in a decline in the count-based dependent variable for the treatment group compared to the control group.
I was thinking that something like a Poisson ANOVA with repeated measures, along with post hoc pairwise comparisons (perhaps using Wilcoxon signed-rank tests), or alternatively, a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM) might be appropriate.

Do you mean that each site was replicated twice (once before, once after), or that you have multiple replicates per site, both before and after?

Okay, then we're almost there, just one piece of information missing: Are the before and after observations performed at the same, or new replicates per site? (In other words, are the before and after measurements paired?)

@FransRodenburg Sorry if it was not clear. Yes, you are correct, all the replicates are at the same sites--paired data.

Please add this new information as an edit to the post, not only as comments.  Comments can be deleted, and are often seen by few people

@kjetilbhalvorsen Updated
